# Как удалить обьект без значения в JSON с помощью js?

Tags: javascript, json

Есть такой JSON

```
{"name":"Вася", "phone":"789654321","name":"", "phone":""}
```

Как мне удалить c помощью js пустой обьект в json ?

то есть если name и phone === null то его не должно быть в фале, а файл большой и именований много.

Comment: `JSON.parse(string); delete json['name'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Для начала уточнение

Существование такого объекта...

```js
{ "name": "Вася", "phone": "789654321", "name": "", "phone": "" }
```

...в JSON невозможно. Так как, поскольку имена ключей повторяются, при разборе она станет таким...

```js
{ name: "", phone: "" }
```

поэтому я думаю что вы имеете в виду такие объекты:

```js
[
    { "name": "Вася", "phone": 789654321 },
    { "name": "", "phone": "" },
    { "name": "Женя", "phone": 111111111 }
]
```

## Решение

А для таких объектов советую такое решение:
при получении объекта разбираем его из JSON, фильтруем и оставляем те объекты в котором `name` и `phone` не `null` и собирая обратно в JSON присваиваем переменной.

```js
let list = `[
    { "name": "Вася", "phone": 789654321 },
    { "name": "", "phone": "" },
    { "name": "Женя", "phone": 111111111 }
]`;

list = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(list).filter(item => !(item.name === null || item.phone === null)));
```

## Ещё момент

При разборе JSON где у ключа отсутствует значение мы получим не `null`, а пустую строку, поэтому правильнее будет так:

```js
let list = `[
    { "name": "Вася", "phone": 789654321 },
    { "name": "", "phone": "" },
    { "name": "Женя", "phone": 111111111 }
]`;

list = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(list).filter(item => !(item.name === `` || item.phone === `` )));
```